# Is it possible to get the geolocation of the computer via the API?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui

I have the task that finds the nearest museum by location, but it only works on phones. I do not know if I can make it work for computers as well?

```cs
[ICommand]
async Task GetClosestMuseum(MuseumModels museum)
{
    //if (IsBusy || Museums.Count == 0)
    // return;
 
    try
    {
        // Get cached location, else get real location.
        var location = await geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
        if (location is null)
        {
            location = await geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest
            {
                DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
            });
        }
        if (location is null) return;
        // Find closest monkey to us
        var first = Museums.OrderBy(m => location.CalculateDistance(
            Convert.ToDouble(m.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(m.Longitude), DistanceUnits.Miles)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (first is null) return;
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Closest Museum", $"{first.Name} in {first.Address}", "OK");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!", $"Unable to get closest museum:{ex.Message}", "OK");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the code you provided and also meet the question that Windows platform can't access location.

But I solved this issue. In Windows 11, in Location privacy settings my Location services wasn't on. So, I turned it on, and now it is working.

In addition, if you also want to run it on Android platform, remember to add this to your AndroidManifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```